# One of the devices behind the switch has IPv6 disconnected from time to time, other is fine

Tags: ethernet, dhcp, ipv6, openwrt

I have two devices, my computer and an Openwrt-flashed router, both connected to the switch and obtain ipv6 address from it. The router is normal, but after a restart for the computer, after a period the ipv6 connectivity is lost: one cannot ping it from outside, and it can't pass any test on test-ipv6.com. But, the router and the computer can ping each other. Restarting `networking` and `network-manager` might restore the situation, but not definitely.
What should I investigate?